# Benchmarking websites via a browser to check loading times of a server?

Tags: internet-explorer, benchmark, firefox, google-chrome

I'm looking for a benchmarking tool to help find out the loading times of a website, I what to be able to run it like 250 times automatically to work out if a series of changes improves things or not.

I tried to use the tool https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/extensions/how-the-extension-system-works/chrome-benchmarking-extension but it doesn't work in Chrome 38+

If that was working it would be perfect, anyone got any knowledge of a good alternative?